# Finding 3d-poses with solvePnP (python, opencv) is off. why?

Tags: python, opencv, calibration

I calibrated my camera following [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) tutorial, using 20 images of a point pattern.
The drawn point centers look suitable, however the reprojection error I obtain is 11.5 pixel -which seems large to me? No subpixeling is done yet.

Next, I am using the same images with the calibration data from above to find the poses of the point pattern, using solvePnP-function.
Here, as shown in the following pictures - it seems as if the center is always found correctly, however the drawn tripod is off  - its ends should correspond to

```
(1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,-1)
```

respectively.

My question is - why is the tripod off randomly - I would be happy about any hint.

Thanks

unfortunately not having any rep - i cant post pictures here. Thus just links...

 [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoEok.jpg) 
 [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT4oj.png) 
 [img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pa3w.png) 
 [img 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfpNL.jpg)  
 [img 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJu0x.jpg)

**Update:**
It seems to be a problem with using solvePnP:
I reprojected all the objectpoints during calibration at their found position - which looks good:

[calibration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZKPa.jpg)

However, when using solvePnP different rvecs and tvecs are returned, resulting in wrong projections of the object points.

[solvePnP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBwZw.jpg)

Any thoughts are welcome ;-)

Here the code how solvePnP is used:

```
#gray is a grayvalue img of calib plate
#objp is an array of floats containing objpoints
#camera matrix and dist. coeff are imported from previous calibration

axis = np.float32([[1,0,0], [8,0,0], [0,0,-1]])
shape = (4,11)
ret, centers = cv2.findCirclesGrid( \
        gray, shape,  flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID)
if ret == True:
    # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
    ret, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objp, centers, camera_matrix, 
                        distortion_coefficients)
    # project 3D points to image plane
    imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, camera_matrix, 
                  distortion_coefficients)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in distortion coefficients. Probably, these coefficients differ to much for images, which should not be. Try to calibrate your camera with this tutorial :
https://learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30584828)